# Discord.net send a message through console

Tags: c#, discord.net

use the console (type things into it) in order to send a message to a sepcified channel id , below is the closest i've gotten.

```
            public static async Task sendMessage()
        {
            string message;
            string idString;
            ulong id;
            Console.WriteLine("message plz");
            message = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("channel plz");
            idString = Console.ReadLine();
            id = Convert.ToUInt64(idString);
            DiscordSocketClient _client = new DiscordSocketClient(); // 2
            ITextChannel channel = (ITextChannel)_client.GetChannel(id); // 4
            await channel.SendMessageAsync(message);
        }
```

some of it is copy pasted from the internet, some isn't. the problem i found through debugging is the channel does not get set from                 `ITextChannel channel = (ITextChannel)_client.GetChannel(id); // 4`

Comment: You need to actually login with and start the client so that it connects to the relevant guilds. You can refer to [this](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/getting_started/first-bot.html#creating-a-discord-client)

Comment: I have done that. to be clear this is just the function i am using. there is still a bot connected with a ping command working

Comment: Then u need to use that original client. You are creating a new one that isn't connected.

Comment: Thanks! Copy pasting from the internet has failed me, luckily stackoverflow hasn't